# I have problems with JSON - Data is repeated

Tags: ios, swift

I have a app and problem is repeating the data inside tableView.

**How do I fix data replication inside Array ?**

```
func jsonGet(page: Int) {
    let pathFull = "https://test.com"
    guard let url = URL(string: pathFull) else {return} //
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do {
            let posts =  try JSONDecoder().decode(JobsData.self, from: data)
            for post in posts.jobs.data {
                self.newsPost.append(post)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        } catch let jsonErr {
            self.alertViewBaisc(title: "erorr", text: "error", button: "ok")
            print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Comment: This file Models Codable :
https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/2hvk

Comment: dataTask runs in the background, so you can't expect it to run multiple times correctly. Furthermore, keep a identifier for each object and before assigning the object to array check if it already exists in the array. This video might prove helpful:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFvs6eraBXM&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGKdVUtA5xds1zcyzsz7HLj&index=7&t=4s

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you are keep inserting in `newsPost` data see                 `self.newsPost.append(post)` Line

Replace  your code with

```
func jsonGet(page: Int) {
    let pathFull = "https://test.com"
    guard let url = URL(string: pathFull) else {return} //
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do {
            let posts =  try JSONDecoder().decode(JobsData.self, from: data)
            var tempPost = [DataType]()
            for post in posts.jobs.data {
                tempPost.append(post)
            }
           self. newsPost =  tempPost

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        } catch let jsonErr {
            self.alertViewBaisc(title: "erorr", text: "error", button: "ok")
            print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Also another way is you can check that if post is already in your array or not

`(self. newsPost.filter{$0.uniqueKey == post.uniqueKey}.count == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the arr with every call

```
self.newsPost.removeAll()
```

or declare it like

```
var newsPost = Set<Post>() // this will guarantee uniqueness in a single fetch
```

also you don't need a for - loop you can directly do

```
newsPost = posts.jobs.data
```

apart from the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains` to sort out this issue:

```
let posts =  try JSONDecoder().decode(JobsData.self, from: data)
            for post in posts.jobs.data {
                if self.newPost contains(post){
                    //Skip
                 }
                 else{
                     self.newsPost.append(post)
                 }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
for post in posts.jobs.data {
    self.newsPost.append(post)
}
```

with

```
self.newsPosts = posts.jobs.data
```

This avoids the redundant repeat loop as well as the duplicate entries since the new data replaces the old.